# Why can't I access a constant from an object?

Tags: c#

```
public class Foo
{
    public const int type = 1;
}
```

**Why can't i do this?** Is there a reason behind it or am I trying to access the constant in a wrong way?

```
new Foo().type;
```

---

I know I can do `Foo.type` but given my scenario, I cant do that. For example if I have two class which inherit from a base class like this:

```
public class Base
{
    ...
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    public const int type = 0;
}

public class Bar : Base
{
    public const int type = 1;
}

public static void printType(Base b)
{
     Console.WriteLine(b.type);
}
```

I would want to get the `type` property of the class sent through the printType() function but I cant since I can only access the `type` from the Class, not the object its self.

A work around would be to do

```
if(b is Foo){
    Console.Write(Foo.type);
}elseif....
```

but this seems stupid and not viable if you have many sub classes of `Base`

---

## Solution

I ended up using `readonly` instead of `const` like this:

```
public readonly int type = 0;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you're trying to access it in the wrong way. A constant isn't associated with an *instance* of a type - it's associated with the type itself. So you want:

```
int x = Foo.type;
```

Basically, `const` members are implicitly static, and C# doesn't let you access static members as if they were instance members, via a value. (Note that in .NET naming conventions, it should be `Type` rather than `type`.)

EDIT: Now that you've explained the actual situation, it appears you're trying to use polymorphism, which won't work for constants. So instead, you should have an abstract property in the base class, implemented in subclasses.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract int Type { get; }
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    public override int Type { get { return 0; } }
}

public class Bar : Base
{
    public override int Type { get { return 0; } }
}
```

Alternatively, just have a normal property in the base class which is populated via the base class constructor:

```
public class Base
{
    private readonly int type;
    public int Type { get { return type; } }

    protected Base(int type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    public Foo() : base(0) {}
}

public class Bar : Base
{
    public Bar() : base(1) {}
}
```

Comment: (On the other hand, I don't think .NET naming conventions support creation of naming collisions with public members of the `global::System` namespace)

Comment: @BenVoigt: There are plenty of counter-examples to that, such as `EventSource.Guid` and `DebuggerDisplayAttribute.Type`. In most cases, that collision won't be an issue at all... it would only cause problems within the `Foo` type itself (or subtypes). Elsewhere, you'd refer to `Foo.Type`, which isn't ambiguous.

Comment: @Jon Yes I know I can do that but given my scenario or what I am trying to do, I can't use that way. Have a look at my example in my edit

Comment: @Krimson: You should have explained that to start with. You're trying to use polymorphism where it simply doesn't apply...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I presume those examples actually match their eponymous type?  Variables sharing a name with their type (`Color Color` is *very* common) are a different case from using an identifier that programmers already have particular expectations about.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well `DebuggerDisplayAttribute.Type` is a string. But I thought your problem was with naming collisions, which isn't the same thing as missed expectations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yea I am using `readonly` instead of constant.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want something to identify the dynamic (most-derived) type of the object passed in, that's built into .NET, via the `Object.GetType()` method.

```
public static void printType(Base b)
{
     Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().Name);
}
```

Of course, this isn't quite the same as having attached data under your control.  You can, however, use a `Dictionary<Type, T>` to associate data of arbitrary type with the various subclasses.  It would be reasonable to use the subclass type initializer to install new entries into such a dictionary.

```
public class Base
{
    static internal readonly Dictionary<System.Type, int> TypeMap =
       new Dictionary<System.Type, int>();
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    static Foo { TypeMap.Add(typeof(Foo), 0); }
}

public class Bar : Base
{
    static Bar { TypeMap.Add(typeof(Bar), 1); }
}

public static void printType(Base b)
{
     Console.WriteLine(Base.TypeMap[b.GetType()]);
}
```

This WILL be a bit slower than the field-per-object method, however it doesn't add any extra storage per-object.

Comment: Note: This is unfortunately considerably susceptible to copy+paste errors (anyone catch them pre-ninja-edit?)

Comment: Your Foo Foo wasn't matched with a Bar Bar

Comment: @demoncodemonkey: Thanks!  The first two copy+paste errors I caught myself.  You got #3.  I wonder how many more there can be.